# The amount of heat produced in muscles. A wrong answer

Tags: muscles

I'm trying to find how energy is released during muscle contraction. Seeing how no work is being produced, the issue is, after working out how much heat was theoretically produced by the heaviest deadlift. First, to give context, the heaviest deadlift I know of is 502.5 kg. Assuming he lifted it up at a acceleration of .5 m/s^2, we can add the gravitational pull to get a rounded answer of 11 m/s^2. Multiplying by the weight gets 5527.5 N. Assuming he lifted it for 1 meter, we get that in joules. Then, taking that he took a second to lift it, gives an answer of 5527.5 Watts. Now, I know a lot assuming was done to get this answer, but all guessed values were rather small, so it shouldn't effect anything. Not only this, but I read that are muscles are around 25% efficient, so the amount of heat produced would be 16582.5 Watts. That's 16 kilowatts. Maybe its just me, but that seems like way to high an answer. Could someone explain?

Comment: A workout where no work is being produced would need to be isometric. Lifting barbells is *work*.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! You seem to have slightly confused the basic terms in physics. To lift a weight with mass $m=500 \, \rm kg$ for a distance $h=1\,m$ up, you need $A=\Delta W_p=mgh = 4900 \, \rm J$ of energy. With some rough assumptions, we can say that the muscle efficiency is indeed $25\,\%$, which means that approximately $3A=15\,\rm kJ$ of heat was produced. This heat warmed the body, and also gets transfered to the environment. Note that Watts are units of _power_, which is $P=A/t$.